# WPF: How to show output of a database?

Tags: sql, wpf, controls

I have a database consisting of 4 or 5 columns, and i want to provide a simple display for that. What WPF control would be best suited to showing the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [WPF Toolkit grid](http://wpf.codeplex.com/). Alternatively, depending on editing requirements, you could just use a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx).

Comment: ListView ought to work, but i can't seem to get it in Details mode. How would i do that with WPF? (sorry for all the dumb questions, i just started with WPF like 3 hours ago!)

Comment: The example in the linked documentation is in details mode (called the GridView view in WPF).